# How To Terminate Thread When Jsp Page close that call it JSP?

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

I am calling a thread in JSP page and that thread keeps on running. I want this thread to terminate when I close the JSP page. Wow would that be possible ?

my code put it in body tag JSP:

```
<%
Thread Ping=new PingThread();
Ping.Start();
%>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is not good idea to use new thread in JSP, JSP is presentation layer.

Comment: This terrible idea.  Why don't you just tell us exactly what it is that you are *really* trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

You mean close it when the user closes the window? There is no event fired for that, so you can't do it. You could do that via JavaScript by making an Ajax call when the user closes the window, but it's probably not going to work anyway.

The doubt that comes to mind is: why would you do such an horrible thing as starting a thead in a JSP page? By spamming the F5 button someone could obtain the easiest DOS attack of the history! Rethink your application to avoid such a solution (launching threads blindly on request, not just the fact that you do it from a JSP).

Answer (score 3):

If you start a thread from a JSP, it is to impossible to guarantee that the thread will be stopped when the user exits the page.

- No notification is sent from the client to server when the user closes or moves away from a plain HTML page.  None whatsoever.
- You could include some javascript in a web page to perform an AJAX call to your server when the user closes the window or moves to a different page.  However, there are scenarios where call won't get made; e.g.

  - the user's machine dies,
  - the user's browser crashes,
  - the user has javascript turned off,
  - the user sets a breakpoint in your code,
  - etcetera.

  And even if the call is made, there's no guarantee that it won't get lost due to some transient networking problem.

The end result will be that your server has an orphaned thread that will keeping doing whatever it is doing (in this case, pounding some other machine with ICMP packets) until you kill your web container.

That's a really, really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript `beforeunload` or `unload` events to determine that the window is being closed, though which one you use and how depends on precisely what it is you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As [Anthony Grist's answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8908383/50776) (sort of), you can embed javascript in your web page to be executed when the browser detects that the current browser window is being closed.  Refer to this page for more details about [DOM Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) and their handling.

Notes:

- This stuff works whether or not the page is a JSP.  (For instance ... it would work if the page was plain HTML ... provided that there was something on the server end to deal with the notification.)
- This event handling is performed *in the users web browser*.
- The server side doesn't get told about the window closing, unless the event handlers send an (AJAX) request to the server to tell it.
- As I said in an answer to a previous question, there event handling can be disabled on the client side by the user.
- As I said in an answer to a previous question, there is no guarantee that the AJAX request will actually make it back to the server.
- All of this adds up to the fact that any server side handling of the window close event is **unreliable**.  And there's no solution to that.  Not in theory, and not in practice.

Answer (score -1):

you could enclose the above in another loop which is set to true by the jsp page throuh ajax call on a time to time basis. if the jsp page is not setting the value to true then you can safely assume that the browser is closed. But you would need an identifier for your thread like say session id or ip of the user.

Comment: *"... then you can safely assume that the browser is closed."* - That's not a safe assumption.  For example, there could just have been a network outage, or the user could have hibernated his / her machine.  However the OP could deem these scenarios as being equivalent to the window closing.  The other problem is that this approach doesn't detect the event in a timely fashion.